# Polymer data binding change listener?

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have this auto-binding template:

```
<template class="event-listener" is="dom-bind">
      <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
        <section data-route="one">
        </section>
        <section data-route="two"></section>
      </iron-pages>
</template>
```

I can set the value of route in javascript, for example:

```
var app = document.querySelector(".event-listener");
app.route = "one";
```

How do I add a listener whenever the value of `route` change?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a listener to detect changes to `route` almost certainly implies that you should create a regular Polymer element, instead of using the `dom-bind`-style element.

By way of example, you might instead ad the following to the `head`:

```
<dom-module is='my-el'>
<script>
Polymer({
    is: 'my-el',
    properties: {
        route: {
            type: String,
            observer: 'routeChanged'
        }
    },
    routeChanged: function() {
        // change fires here
    }
});
</script>
<template>
      <iron-pages attr-for-selected="data-route" selected="{{route}}">
        <section data-route="one">
        </section>
        <section data-route="two"></section>
      </iron-pages>
</template>
</dom-module>
```

And somewhere in the `body`:

```
<my-el></my-el>
<script>
document.querySelector('my-el').route = "one";
</script>
```